# Ativar o GPS do smartphone

Tags: android, google-maps, app, gps

Estou desenvolvendo um app que utiliza as funções de geolocalização. O mesmo já está pegando as localizações do smartphone, e consigo verificar se a conexão do GPS ou não. 
Até ai tranquilo, o que não estou conseguindo é que se o GPS estiver desligado, peça para o usuário ligar o mesmo, levando-o direto a tela de configurações do GPS, ou apenas com um clique de um turn on no GPS e não deixe o mesmo utilizar o app até que seja ligado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Atualmente não é possível ativar/desativar o *GPS* diretamente do aplicativo, porém, você pode sim levar o usuário para a configuração do dispositivo que faz isso.

Para isso, após fazer essa verificação do *GPS* e constatar que está desligado, o usuário pode tocar um botão que terá esta ação simples para abrir a `Activity` de configuração:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
```

Agora, fazer com que o aplicativo não seja utilizado até que o *GPS* esteja pronto, você mesmo já possui a solução, já que faz a verificação de disponibilidade dele, certo?

Comment: Valeu @Paulo, funcionou sim, exatamente isso que queria, agora só basta fazer uma janela com um para ir para a startActivity.

Comment: Ótimo! Considere marcar esta resposta como aceita caso tenha respondido sua dúvida. Assim irá ajudar outros com a mesma dúvida.